# map of vectors in STL?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to have a map of vectors, (but I don't want to use pointer for the internal vector), is it possible?

```
// define my map of vector
map<int, vector<MyClass> > map;

// insert an empty vector for key 10. # Compile Error
map.insert(pair<int, vector<MyClass> >(10, vector<MyClass>));
```

I know that if I have used pointer for vector, as follows, it would be fine, but I wonder if I can avoid using pointer and use the above data structure (I don't want to manually delete)

```
// define my map of vector
map<int, vector<MyClass>* > map;

// insert an empty vector for key 10.
map.insert(pair<int, vector<MyClass>* >(10, new vector<MyClass>));
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first data structure will work. You might want to `typedef` some of the code to make future work easier:

```
typedef std::vector<MyClass>      MyClassSet;
typedef std::map<int, MyClassSet> MyClassSetMap;

MyClassSetMap map;
map.insert(MyClassSetMap::value_type(10, MyClassSet()));
```

or (thanks [quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana)):

```
map[10] = MyClassSet();
```

Answer (score 20):

Yes, but your second line should be:

```
map.insert(pair<int, vector<MyClass> >(10, vector<MyClass>()));
```

This inserts a pair consisting of the integer 10, and an empty vector. Both will be copied, and if you're dealing with large vectors then you'll want to be careful about copies.

Also: don't call variables "map" while `using namespace std`. You're scaring me ;-)

Comment: It's even easier to write `map.insert( std::make_pair( 10, vector<MyClass>() ) );`

Comment: @xtofl: yes, I meant "should" in the sense of "to get rid of the compiler error". fbrereton also makes good points about making the code more concise.

Comment: +1 for pointed out "using map with std namespace" :)
Scared me too

Comment: why not use the type inside map. map::value_type!

Comment: @xtofl. Its even easier to use the [] operator. (see below)

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `[]` operator.

It will insert the value into the map:

```
map[10]; // create the 10 element if it does not exist
         // using the default constructor.
```

If you are going to use the value soon after construction then:

```
std::vector<MyClass>&  v = map[10];
```

Now it's constructed and you have a local reference to the object.

Answer (score 6):

Using the typedefs from fbrereton you can also do this:

```
typedef std::vector<MyClass>      MyClassSet;
typedef std::map<int, MyClassSet> MyClassSetMap;

MyClassSetMap map;
map[10]=MyClassSet();
```

You can use `operator[]` instead of `insert().`  This saves on the line noise a bit.

Comment: I think you meant map[10] = MyClassSet(); Actually it should also be possible to write just map[10]; (to add a small element of surprise).

Comment: @UncleBens - Oops, yup, I'll fix it!

Comment: This depends upon how this is called. Insert may be faster if you know there will be no conflicts.

Answer (score 6):

Use the swap function to efficiently add your vector.

```
map<int, vector<SomeClass> > Map;

vector<SomeClass> vec;
//...add elements to vec

Map[1] = vector<int>();
// swap the empty vector just inserted with your vector.
Map[1].swap(vec);
```

Answer (score 5):

<sup>You should read compile error messages. They usually gives you all information that you need.</sup>
Your code gives error `'illegal use of this type as an expression'` in that string. That means that you use type, not an object. To use an object you could just add () for calling constructor with no arguments.

```
map.insert(pair<int, vector<MyClass> >(10, vector<MyClass>()));
```

By the way you could use std::make_pair to create pairs. It deduces argument types, so no need to explicitly indicate them.

```
map.insert( make_pair( 10, vector<MyClass>() ) );
```

Comment: +1 for suggestion to read compiler errors. However, they are compiler-specific. With GCC the error is "expected primary-expression before ...", which IMO has a generic meaning of "something's wrong here" - you just need to take a good look at the code to figure it out. (Trying to compile with different compilers might be a good idea, I've had error messages that are not only unclear but misleading, e.g "second parameter is wrong" where the error was in the first parameter.)

Answer (score 3):

Lets use a little bit c++11 ;)

```
typedef std::vector<MyClass>      MyClassSet;
typedef std::map<int, MyClassSet> MyClassSetMap;

MyClassSetMap map;
map.emplace(myid, MyClassSet());
```

To know if this was inserted you can do:

```
const auto result = map.emplace(myid, MyClassSet());
return (result.second) 
? "Is_OK"
: "Maybe "+myid+" exists\n";
```

And here is the **flagship** of c++11 and maps.... how to insert in this map a pair if it doesn't exists and if it exists just insert a new element in the vector....

```
const auto result = map.emplace(myid, MyClassSet());
result.first->second.emplace(objSet);
```

I hope give a useful information!!!

Comment: If my memory serves, map class doesn't provide "emplace_back" function (it relatively belongs to vector and other containers). map in other hands provides "emplace" and "emplace_hint" functions

Comment: Yes, completly  agree. Ediited, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are just missing a pair of parenthesis:

```
map.insert(pair<int, vector<MyClass> >(10, vector<MyClass>()));
```

Incidentally, there's a helper function std::make_pair which takes care of deducing the template arguments:

```
map.insert(make_pair(10, vector<MyClass>()));
```

Considering using a pointer to dynamically allocated vector instead is a rather bad idea, since this will make you responsible for managing the instance. Also, since map should never move its contents around in memory, there is nothing to gain performance-wise neither.

Answer (score -2):

```
// define my map of vector
map<int, vector<MyClass> > map;
MyClass *ptr = new MyClass();
map[0].push_back(ptr);
```

pushing objects into vector of type MyClass

```
//usage; map[0][vector_index]
map[0][0]->MyClassMember;
```

accessing member functions using vector_index