# Constructing a Map With Vectors as Values

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, iterator

I am trying to construct a map that maps a string to a vector of unsigned integers. The way that I construct this map is as follows:

```
void PixelP1ROCDACSettings::getDACs(map<string,vector<unsigned int>>& dacs) const
{
    dacs.clear();
    dacs.insert(pair<string, vector<unsigned int> > (k_DACName_Vdd, make_vector(Vdd_, k_DACAddress_Vdd)));
    dacs.insert(pair<string, vector<unsigned int> > (k_DACName_Vana,make_vector(Vana_, k_DACAddress_Vana)));
    ...
}
```

Where make_vector is defined as follows:

```
   std::vector<unsigned int> make_vector(unsigned int DACValue, 
                                         unsigned int DACAddress) const ;
```

My questions are:
1) I would like to get access each individual value in my vector, I've tried to do, 
`dacs[key][index]` but that didn't seem to work.  Is there a special syntax to do this?

2) Additionally, I would like to iterate across my map, How would I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possibly related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380585/map-of-vectors-in-stl

Comment: `dacs[key][index]` should work, can you give more details on why it is not working?
Iterating over map: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844886/how-to-loop-through-a-c-map

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c++11 you can iterate with

```
for (auto& keyvaluepair : dacs) {
     //keyvaluepair.first is your string
     //keyvaluepair.second is your vector
}
```

also dacs[key][index] is the correct way to access the indexth element in the vector mapped to by key.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but now I am getting the following error: >src/common/PixelFECInterface.cc:2674: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token